# How do I replace NaNs with the values from another row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, imputation

I have a df with some rows that contain NaNs. I want to impute those with the respective variable values of that row's most similar row. I created a subset of my df with all the rows that have NaNs and created a list with indices of the most similar rows to the ones in the subset. 
I now have the ID of a row with missing values and the ID of the most similar row to that one.

Let's say this is my df:

```py
    ID  A   B   C
    01  10  20  40.0
    02  12  19  43.0
    03  10  NaN NaN
```

What I want, is to replace the NaN with some other row's values.
Expected outcome:

```py
    ID  A   B   C
    01  10  20  40.0
    02  12  19  43.0
    03  10  20  40.0
```

This doesn't seem to do the trick:

```py
    df.loc[df['ID'] == 03]['B'] = df.loc[df['ID'] == 01]['B']
```

Ideally I would just fillna() all NaNs in a row with the values from another row.

Comment: You could compute the euclidean distance matrix, look for the most similar rows to the available columns in a specific row, and use them to fill the missing values

Comment: I already did this, but couldn't figure out a proper way to replace them. I was looking for something like @MarkWang posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `fillna` with a column or row,

```
df.fillna(df.iloc[0])
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, THANKS!!